# Using division and Modulos

Tags: c++, math

I am new to C++ ( I am a Java developer) and studying it by my self. I need to seperate the following number "12345" into indivudial numbers, which means in this case 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. My book says it can be done by without the help of any inbuilt c++ method. How is that? Please help! And I found that modulo and devision can help. But how? I don't know! Please help!

Comment: Try something and we will help, if you have any troubles.

Comment: Here's a hint: work from right to left.

Comment: How would you do it in Java? You're a Java developer, then you should be able to do that in Java, right?

Comment: Good hint by @chris. Think about it.

Comment: "*it can be done without the help of any inbuilt c++ method*" - what does that even mean?

Comment: @yohan I think you've got the right idea in your title.  Modulo is '%'.  Try starting to code and see what kind of output you get.

Comment: @Nawaz: If this is Java, I will make it a String, and turn it into a char array. Then you know, other conversions and operations will happen.

Comment: @MartyE: Yes, after some search, I found modulo and devision can help! But how?

Comment: @Yohan: Is that the only way you can do it in Java? Any other approach? (Also, at the point, I think it is not clear as to what you want: you want `1` as char (like `'1'`)? or int (as `1`)?

Comment: @Yohan modulo such as `int y = 12345 % 2` would equal `1`.  You'll probably want to plug in different numbers, but we'll leave those up to you for the challenge.

Comment: Thanks for the reply all. I really think I need some vacation. It seems like I am acting like an idiot, because my mind is not working properly. I sleep only 2 hours per day or no sleep, for the past 3 months. I created this program at 3 am I guess. I am a student actually, I got lot to self study because I like, but I guess the way I followed is not good :( .  I will be out from programming for at least 1 week :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep dividing (/) the number by 10.  The remainders (%) of each division give you the digits in reverse order.

Comment: Correct, but he might have actually learned something if he figured it out himself with a few hints rather than a spoon-feeding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply all. I really think I need some vacation. It seems like I am acting like an idiot, because my mind is not working properly. I sleep only 2 hours per day or no sleep, for the past 3 months. I am a student actually, I got lot to self study because I like, but I guess the way I followed is not good :( . I will be out from programming for at least 1 week :(